# Not able to rename ejb-jar_XXX.xml to ejb-jar.xml inside META-INF in ANT

Tags: java, ant

There is a file inside META-INF folder ejb-jar_XXX.xml which I need to rename to ejb-jar.xml using ant.

In ant script we are using following task to include files in META-INF:

```
<metainf dir="${generic-build.src}/META-INF" includes="**/*.xml" />
```

I tried

```
<metainf dir="${generic-build.src}/META-INF" includes="**/*.xml" excludes="**/ejb-jar.xml"/>
<move file="ejb-jar_XXX.xml" tofile="ejb-jar.xml"/>
```

but got error

> jar doesn't support the nested "move" element.

I also tried rename but same error message.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of Ant are you using?

Comment: @abarisone ant 1.8.3

Comment: Could you show all of the jar task?

Answer (score 0):

On [Coderanch blog post](http://www.coderanch.com/t/477041/tools/jar-type-doesn-support-nested) I found a similar case to yours.
It is related to the `copy` task but the concept seems the same.

I think you should put the `move` task outside the `jar` task to get it done without errors.